# Django form EmailField doesn't accept the css attribute

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates

I have a from containing some fields, but my `css` class applies to all the fileds except the `EmailField`. I've also tried `sender.widget.attrs.update({'class':"contatct-form"})` and it still doesn't work (just change the size of field). Does anybody knows what the problem is? as all of my searches were unsuccessful.

form:

```
from django import forms
class NameForm(forms.Form):
     your_name = forms.CharField(initial='Your name', max_length=100)
     sender = forms.EmailField()
     #sender.widget.attrs.update({'class':"contatct-form"})
     message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
```

template:

```
        <div class="contatct-form">
            <form action="" method="post">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{ form }}
                <input type="submit" value="send" />
            </form>
        </div>
```

Comment: have you tried with `sender = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'contatct-form'}))`. Btw isnt `contatct-form` a typo ?

Comment: @Todor yes, not its not!

Comment: BTW, when i test your code in the python shell its working. (i get the `"contatct-form"` class included `<tr><th><label for="id_sender">Sender:</label></th><td><input class="contatct-form" id="id_sender" name="sender" type="email" /></td></tr>
`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem you have probably is because you have not assigned any **widget** to your **EmailField()**, change to this (like @Todor said) should work:

```
...
sender = forms.EmailField(
    widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class': 'contatct-form'})
)
```

If this doesn't work for whatever reason (probably wrong css styling), you can just change the styling in your **css**/**class** directly like so:

```
div.contatct-form form input[type=email] {
    /* your changes here... */
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks buddy! in my `css`  the ` input type` was `text`, but i shouldn't use `email` type for that , because the other inputs may be like email field i just removed the `type` at all!

Answer (score 1):

We have to do that in the **init** method for one field or all fields with for loop.

```
class NameForm(forms.Form):
def __init__(*args, **kwargs):
    super(NameForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['sender'].widget.attrs.update({'class':"contatct-form"})
```